# Should a lock/unlock button show state or functionality?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

#### Purpose

Allow enabling/disabling of a text field, by a lock/unlock icon

#### Proposed

Icon show *state*

i.e. when locked, show locked icon

when unlocked, show unlocked icon

#### Question

When toggling between locked/unlocked state, it seems counterintuitive to click the locked icon, but the action is actually `unlocking` the text field.

Should I show the functionality instead of state instead?

[unlocked icon button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYteO.png)

[locked icon button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac7DB.png)

Comment: When you unlock a physical lock is it locked or open?

Comment: @epascarello I see what you mean, but I think a physical lock requires a `key`, while user are merely using tap/click behavior, which is not very obvious for them

Comment: So give it animation when they interact with it on hover to give hint something happens.

Comment: @epascarello that's a great point, thanks!

Comment: This is more of a user experience question than a programming question, and has been answered on Stack Exchange UX: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/40954/12864